# PDO não retorna os resultados de consulta

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho um código onde você teria um select para selecionar em qual coluna você quer procurar e clica na letra para buscar dentro da coluna selecionada a letra selecionada.

O erro está no meu botão. Ele teria que ser um `<a href="">` só que por ter um `<form action="">` direcionado a outra página o `href` entra em conflito com o `form`

**Código de busca letra "A":**

```
require_once 'functions.php';

    $PDO = db_connect();

    $opcao_filtro = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'opcao_filtro', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM tablet AS t WHERE';

  //idlivro, titulo, tipo, e cor.
  switch($opcao_filtro)
  {
      switch($opcao_filtro)
{

    case 'titulo': {
        $sql .= ' t.titulo like "a%"';
        break;
    }
    case 'cor': {
        $sql .= ' t.cor like "a%"';
        break;
    }
    case 'categoria': {
        $sql .= ' t.categoria like "a%"';
        break;
    }
}


    $stmt = $PDO->prepare($sql);
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $result = array_unique($rows);

        foreach($rows as $row)
        {
            echo $row['titulo'];
            echo $row['cor'];
            echo $row['categoria'];
        }
```

**Tag do botão:**

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-link btn-xs" value="a" name="a">A</button>
```

**Select:**

```
<div class="op">
    <select name="opcao_filtro" class="form-control" style="width:150px; height:30px;">
        <option value="nulo">---</option>                
        <option value="titulo">Título</option>
        <option value="autor">Autor</option>
        <option value="tema">Tema</option>
        <option value="editora">Editora</option>                                    
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Para saber o que está ocorrendo, você pode dar um `print_r($stmt->errorInfo())` logo após o `$stmt = $PDO->prepare($sql)`

Comment: Até assim ele retorna em branco.

Comment: Percebo que você não tem o método execute: `$stmt->execute()` que seria logo após o `$stmt = $PDO->prepare($sql)`

Comment: Adicionei e não funcionou :/

Comment: Adicione essas linhas [aqui](https://github.com/cbcarlos07/servcard/blob/master/include/error.php) no início do arquivo e atualiza pra ver

Comment: Retornou este erro Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in

Answer (score 2):

A montagem do seu `WHERE` esta incorreta, o sinal `?`(interrogação), irá ser substituído pelo parâmetro passado, então o `WHERE` deveria ser montado da seguinte forma:

```
switch($opcao_filtro)
{
    case 'titulo': {
        $sql .= ' t.titulo like "?%"';
        break;
    }
    case 'autor': {
        $sql .= ' t.cor like "?%"';
        break;
    }
    case 'tema': {
        $sql .= ' t.categoria like "?%"';
        break;
    }
}
```

Outro ponto importante a destacar é que, ou você usa o `=`(igual) para comparar valores inteiros, ou você usa o `LIKE` com `%`(porcentagem) para comparar de forma parcial.

Comment: ou usar o bindValue e usar `:valor` no WHERE

Comment: Pensei nessa possibilidade, mas se não me engano, o `bindValue` por padrão utiliza o tipo `PDO::PARAM_STR`, então o conteúdo seria colocado entre aspas.

Comment: As aspas seriam na string geral `$sql .= " t.titulo LIKE :titulo";`

Comment: Não, as aspas devem estar somente no valor digitado pelo usuário e na `%`

Comment: Se fosse usar o bindValue, poderia usar assim: `$stmt->bindValue(':titulo', $titulo)` e inicializar a variável com assim: `$titulo = "%valor"` quem também daria certo